# How can i build a bridge from scatch and of course a secure bridge which no one could hack it?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, vyper

i want to know how bridge work because i want to work on my own bridge for a personnal project. Any good link for documentation and tutorial ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.
We have a blog as well as sample code in this article: [how to create blockchain bridge](https://chainstack.com/how-to-create-blockchain-bridge/). You can get all the information you need here.

This blog post uses Ethereum and Harmony as example. Basically a bridge works like this:

1. When the bridge wallet receives tokens from the Ethereum side of the bridge, it should mint new tokens in the Harmony side and send them to the same user.
2. When the bridge wallet receives tokens from the Harmony side of the bridge, it should burn those tokens and transfer back the same amount of tokens from the bridge wallet to the user.

A bridge can be divided into three parts:

**Smart contracts**: we need two ERC20 token contracts, one in each blockchain that we’re going to bridge. To create and deploy the smart contracts, I’m going to use Hardhat.

**Web app**: the frontend that users will interact with to actually send their tokens accross. I’ll create it with Vue.js and use ethers.js to interact with the smart contracts.

**Backend job**: we also need a process listening to tokens received in the bridge wallet. This job will be written in JavaScript to keep it simple. It’ll use web3.js to interact with our blockchain nodes and smart contracts.

Hope it will help you. Happy coding.